# Error in knockout mapping JSON read

Tags: json, knockout.js, mapping

i am using knockout on web application which displays the data with a foreach 
(all needed libraries are included)

and i get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: d is not defined; Bindings value: foreach: d
[Break On This Error]   

...+c+" } ";return new Function("sc",c)},kb:function(a,b){if(b.compareDocumentPosit...
```

my JSON:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"listingItem:#applicationModel","award_text":"","channel_id":5,"constructed_short_descriptionen":"","constructed_short_descriptiongr":"","constructed_titleen":"","constructed_titlegr":"","country_id"...
```

My Code:

```
var Listing_ViewModel = {};

    var data = $.getJSON("listings.svc/Listing_Get_Items?",
                {
                    startdate: "2012-09-21 00:00:00",
                    stopdate: "2012-09-22 00:00:00",
                    channel_id: "5"
                }, function (data) {
                    // Now use this data to update your view models, 
                    // and Knockout will update your UI automatically 
                    //var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(data.d[0].duration);
                    Listing_ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
                    //alert(ko.mapping.toJS(Listing_ViewModel));
                    ko.applyBindings(Listing_ViewModel);
                    //        ko.applyBindings({
                    //          
                    //        });
                })
```

HTML code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: d -->
    <li class="item item-even" id="id_1" title="1">
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong? Sorry i am completely green!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you are using `fromJSON` when you really mean `fromJS`. `$.getJSON` will already create an object for you while `ko.mapping.fromJSON` reads in a JSON string. `ko.mapping.fromJS` reads in a Javascript Object.

See this JSFiddle for more: http://jsfiddle.net/hB3Rm/

Essentially, change this line:

```
Listing_ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
```

to this line:

```
Listing_ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Comment: It worked! I was so close and was playing around with irrelevant parts of code (e.g. data or data.d).

Thanks a lot! I was convinced that i should use fromJSON instead of fromJS.

So fromJS reads in a Javascript Object and not from a Javascript Object because KO needs javascript objects to work.