# Binding JSON to knockout template does not work

Tags: json, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Hi I have this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "wsCart.asmx/GetShippingRates2",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (d) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(d));
            vm.shippingOptions = ko.mapping.fromJS(d);
        }
});
```

and this is the JSON

```
{"d":"[
    {\"Name\":\"Fedex - Error\",\"InternalName\":\"11\",\"Picture\":null,\"Costs\":0.0,\"Delivery\":\"2013-06-21T13:48:43.8220537+02:00\",\"ExtraInfo\":null},
    {\"Name\":\"Normal shipment\",\"InternalName\":\"normal\",\"Picture\":\"/images/blank.gif\",\"Costs\":2.5,\"Delivery\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"ExtraInfo\":null},
    {\"Name\":\"UPS - Expedited\",\"InternalName\":\"08\",\"Picture\":\"/images/ups-logo.png\",\"Costs\":122.0,\"Delivery\":\"2013-06-21T13:48:37.4170513+02:00\",\"ExtraInfo\":\"\"},
    {\"Name\":\"UPS - Saver\",\"InternalName\":\"65\",\"Picture\":\"/images/ups-logo.png\",\"Costs\":122.46,\"Delivery\":\"2013-06-08T00:00:00\",\"ExtraInfo\":\"\"}]"}
```

and this is my `GetShippingRates2` method:

```
var shipOptions = new List<ShipmentRateOption>();
shipOptions.Add(staticShip);
List<ShipmentRateOption> a = shipOptions.OrderBy(p => p.Costs).ToList();
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

my knockout (viewmodel) has:

```
var shipOptions = [];
function ovm() {
    var self = this;
    self.shippingOptions = ko.observableArray(shipOptions);
}   
var vm = new ovm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The ajax call is triggered by a jquery on click event. The HTML that I have to bind the array to:

```
<table style="width: 60%;">
    <tr data-bind="template: { foreach: shippingOptions() }">
        <td><label><input name="shipmentoptions" type="radio" data-bind="value: Name" /><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></label></td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">&euro;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">pic</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have found several SO questions about this topic, but somehow most of them are MVC. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574387/error-in-knockout-mapping-json-read) came close, but somehow does not help me. I have the JSON mentioned above as alert and have trouble with debugging this and have the felling that the `d:` in the json is causing a problem with the binding. But I cannot find the solution. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

thanks in advance!!

**edit**
changed to `ko.mapping.fromJS(d.d, {}, vm.shippingOptions);`
and `<table style="width: 60%;" data-bind="foreach: shippingOptions">`
but now I get:

[name not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9JgF.png)

Comment: avi, you have my mail lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the `d` in your JSON so you just need to call `fromJS` with `d.d`

```
vm.shippingOptions = ko.mapping.fromJS(d.d);
```

However this wouldn't work alone because to set an observable's value you need call it as function so you need to write:

```
vm.shippingOptions(ko.mapping.fromJS(d.d));
```

However because `fromJS` will return an observable array you will end up with your `shippingOptions` observable array holding another observable array... which is might not what you want.

So for the **final and correct solution** you need to use a different overload of the `fromJS` which takes an already existing array and fills in with the new data:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(d.d, {}, vm.shippingOptions);
```

And in this case you need to remove `()` from your foreach binding:

```
<tr data-bind="template: { foreach: shippingOptions }">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AL42d/).

Comment: Sidenote: in this case (if you don't have a separate named template) you don't need the `template` biding it is enough to write `<tr data-bind="foreach: shippingOptions">`

Comment: Thanks, but the jsFiddle does not render the `</tr>` foreach. When I run the code with your suggestions, I get a `Name` is not recognized?

Comment: I see the binding should be on the table: `<table style="width: 60%;" data-bind="template: { foreach: shippingOptions }">` http://jsfiddle.net/AL42d/1/ Where do you get the Name is not recognized in your own code or in the jsFiddle?

Comment: it is in my own code and I seriously have no clue why it only renders the first line and not even with the correct data. I have added the screenshot of the firebug window

Comment: You can try `ko.mapping.fromJSON` instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS` other than that it is hard to help without you try to reproduce the same behavior in a JSFiddle...

Comment: Probably the `wsCart.asmx/GetShippingRates2` is not returning the right headers/content so `$.ajax` cannot parse your data in the success callback. So what you get in the `d` is a JSON string and not a JS object so you need to use `ko.mapping.fromJSON` to map it.